# Double entry of each input type text in the database laravel javascript using foreach

Tags: javascript, php, database, laravel, autocomplete

i have this in my database.

### Person   | Location

student1    San Francisco

student2    San Francisco

student1    New York

student2    New york

There's a problem in my controller. here is the code:

```
foreach((array)$request->stud as $person){
  foreach((array)$request->studlocation as $location){
    $hm = new HouseMate;

    $hmid = rand();
    $hm->hmid=$hmid;
    $hm->rId_fk=$renterid;
    $hm->person=$person;  

    $hm->location=$location;
    $hm->save();
  }
  $hm->delete();
}
```

And in my view:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dropdown").change(function() {
    var selVal = $(this).val();
    $("#textboxDiv").html('');
    $("#schoolloc").html('');

    if(selVal > 0) {
      for(var i = 1; i<= selVal; i++) {
        $("#textboxDiv").append('<input type="hidden" value="student'+i+'" name="stud[]" />');
        $("#schoolloc").append('<input type="text" name="studlocation[]" id="studlocation'+i+'" />');
        var input = document.getElementById('studlocation'+i+'');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

Code php:

```
$students = (array)$request->stud;
$locations = (array)$request->studlocation;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($studens); i++){
    $hm = new HouseMate;

    $hmid = rand();
    $hm->hmid=$hmid;
    $hm->rId_fk=$renterid;
    $hm->person=$students[i];  

    $hm->location=locations[i];
    $hm->save();
    $hm->delete();
}
```

Comment: Ohmygad thank you so much .... You're a life saver. I've been doing this since yesterday..

Comment: i did vote you, but it say i need 15 reputation for it to be public.

Comment: Done! hey, I have one question left if you don't mind.

Comment: @Cryptanalyst So you should open another question.

Comment: i'll still have to wait for 90 minutes to post huhuhu

Comment: @Cryptanalyst Add it there, we will help you.

Answer (score 1):

the error was starting on this:

" $hm->lat=$slat[$i];"

this is my controller:

```
$students = (array)$request->stud;
$locations = (array)$request->studlocation;
$slat=(array)$request->slat;
$slng=(array)$request->slng;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($students); $i++){
$hm = new HouseMate;
$hmid = rand();
$hm->hmid=$hmid;
$hm->rId_fk=$renterid;
$hm->person=$students[$i];  
$hm->location=$locations[$i];
$hm->lat=$slat[$i];
$hm->lng=$slng[$i];
$hm->save();
```

}

and this is my view:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#dropdown").change(function() {
     var selVal = $(this).val();
     $("#textboxDiv").html('');
     $("#schoolloc").html('');

    if(selVal > 0) {
        for(var i = 1; i<= selVal; i++) {
             $("#textboxDiv").append('<input type="hidden" 
    value="student'+i+'" name="stud[]" />');
             $("#schoolloc").append('<input type="text" 
    name="studlocation[]" id="studlocation'+i+'" />');
        var input = document.getElementById('studlocation'+i+'');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    $("#slat").html('');
    $("#slng").html('');
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

  $("#slat").append('<input type="hidden" name="slat[]" value='+lat+' />');
  $("#slng").append('<input type="hidden" name="slng[]" value='+lng + ' />');
         });
         }
       }
    });
    });
```

Comment: May be you lost the double quote at value attribute.

` 
    $("#slat").append('<input type="hidden" name="slat[]" value="'+lat+'" />');
    $("#slng").append('<input type="hidden" name="slng[]" value="'+lng + '" />');
`

Comment: Could you send me the data of request array?

Comment: what do you mean ? the view or the controller or the schema or the database?

Comment: please do it:
var_dump((array)$request)

Comment: where should i put it?